# .net core 2.2 session timeout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, session-state

I have .net core app deployed azure app service Linux container. The problem is session timeout. One of the user group want no session timeout. The application is shared among different user groups so I don't want to extend the session timeout to hours. Even though I extend, it depends on server pool recycle time. So I add some java script to keep the browser alive. But it doesn't help too. Kindly give any suggestion whether it is possible or jot.

Comment: https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip132.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i don't think this is what I am looking for. I have set the session timeout 30 minutes. But one user group doesn't want to be signed out . They want permanent session which I can't set only for them. Even if I set 10 hours session, I don't think it will last for that long.